# How should we display GeoPackage on Mapbox GL JS?

Tags: netcdf, geopackage, mapbox-gl-js

We used wgrib2 to convert weather radar data into NetCDF format. We converted it to GeoPackage format using gdal_translate. We created a Color Map on QGIS 3.10 and the GeoPackage appeared as expected.

[image]

We would like to display this on the Internet using these files or processed versions of these files. We have Mapbox GL JS as a candidate for that but it is not required. We have not found a way to display the gpkg files we have generated. How can we get it to display?

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/guides/

We generated png images using gdaldem color-relief and we also tried the following method
However, when we zoomed in on the map with this method, the quality of the image was rough and it could not be displayed beautifully.

https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/image-on-a-map/

[image]

Since the gpkg we generated displays correctly in QGIS, it would be most desirable to be able to display the gpkg on MapBox. However, if that is not possible, we would like to display that data beautifully, even in another format.

We also tried to generate tiles using gdal2tiles.py. It worked as we expected when we created data up to zoom level 10. However, when we created the data for zoom level 11, it took more than 12 minutes. Since our data is generated every 5 minutes, we cannot spend any more time on tile generation.

One person recommended GeoServer to us. We installed GeoServer on EC2 but we don't understand how to use it. In this case we just want to create tiles from GeoPackage. What must we do in this case? We placed the gpkg file under the data folder, created a workspace, and then selected GeoPackage under Vector Data Source in Stores and specified the gpkg file. What SQL should we specify here? We know that the gpkg file is SQLite and that there are tables in the file. Perhaps we should specify SQL for this.

Comment: Does it help you if I say this is more a question about how to display *raster data* in MapBoxGL than it is about them being currently in a GeoPackage source?

Comment: Have a look at geopackage-js: https://github.com/ngageoint/geopackage-js

Comment: @bugmenot123
If there is a fast way to display NetCDF or GeoPackage on Mapbox GL JS, we want to know how. But if that is difficult, we would like to know how to provide them in raster or vector tiles using GeoServer. In other words, we are open to any means if we can provide the information we generate, but we can't spend more than 5 minutes on the conversion.

Comment: @TomazicM Thank you. We have seen this before. Maybe we couldn't get it to work once, but we'll try it again.

Comment: @TomazicM We tried uploading our gpkg file to the following site but nothing was rendered. Unfortunately that site does not seem to be compatible with our data. However, our data is rendered correctly in QGIS, so our data seems to be correct. https://ngageoint.github.io/geopackage-js/

Comment: The site where you tried it is just an example of using GeoPackage JS library. Examples don't always work correctly for all kinds of data. You should try your own use of GeoPackage JS library.

Comment: I see. I will try that.